# Trouble with async and Parse

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, aws-lambda

I'm using Parse Server and having trouble with an async function not behaving as expected. I'm running this on Node.js 8.10 on AWS Lambda. Here is a (very simplified) version of my function:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("updateSubscriptions", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    winston.info("Updating subscriptions...");

    var Subscription = Parse.Object.extend("Subscription");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Subscription);

    await query.find().then(
      function () {
        winston.debug("Got subscriptions.");
      },
      function(error) {
        winston.error("Error querying subscriptions.");
      }
    );
    winston.debug("Wrapping up.");
  } catch (e) {
    winston.error("Uh oh.");
  }
});
```

What I want (and expect) is to get the output "Updating subscriptions... Got subscriptions. Wrapping up."

What actually happens is that I see "Updating subscriptions..." and that's all. It appears that the function is not actually waiting on the async call, and/or Lambda is killing the process early.

Does anyone have any clue what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I've noticed that the exact same code works fine as a cloud _function_. It only fails as a cloud _job_. That leads me to believe this is a bug: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/4995

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've explained why it isn't a bug it's by design and on purpose. So you can run things longer that the httpRequest timeout.

If you have a look at the code [here](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/src/Routers/FunctionsRouter.js#L66) you'll see that the handleCloudJob() function goes to great length to isolate the job execution from the request life cycle. This is *BY DESIGN* and *NOT A BUG*.

Now, let's see how it works in lambda:

1. Request comes in
2. handleCloudJob() is called
3. The job is set a [running](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/src/Routers/FunctionsRouter.js#L63)
4. We call process.nextTick() to enqueue the job effective work
5. we return the job status ID.
6. the response is sent with the jobID
7. the job work starts, enqueued by process.nextTick
   ... > time passes
8. the job finishes
9. the jobStatus gets [updated](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/src/Routers/FunctionsRouter.js#L70)

Now imagine for a minute we didn't do that:

at if instead of 6. Sending the response, we were 'awaiting' on the job, like you suggest

What would happen is:

- The timeout for the socket would probably be reached (30s), as jobs are 'long'
- the connection would be closed
- impossible to get the job ID.

Now what happens in you lambda environment:

- the enqueuing is done at step 4,
- at step 6 the response is sent
- the response is sent to the client
- the lambda environment is destroyed.

Which is the expected behaviour.

Can it be better? Perhaps, but that requires a totally different execution environment on jobs. basically worker that await for messages that functions that executes for long time in the background (so not front-end lambdas)

In the lambdas FAQ's it's stated that the [default timeout is 3s](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/?nc1=h_ls) and can be extended to max 300s. So by default lambda isn't suited to run jobs.

While I understand your frustration and that it doens't make sense to 'you', it's all by design.

Even if we swapped the implementation on parse-server it wouldn't make it suited for lambdas to run jobs.